# Merge k sorted lists: Space complexity

Tags: algorithm, priority-queue

```
class Solution(object):
    def mergeKLists(self, lists):
        """
        :type lists: List[ListNode]
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        head = point = ListNode(0)
        q = PriorityQueue()
        for l in lists:
            if l:
                q.put((l.val, l))
        while not q.empty():
            val, node = q.get()
            point.next = ListNode(val)
            point = point.next
            node = node.next
            if node:
                q.put((node.val, node))
        return head.next
```

Hi, I have Python solution for the problem "Merge k sorted lists", 
https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/solution/

In the official solution section it says:

```
O(n) Creating a new linked list costs O(n) space.
O(k) The code above present applies in-place method which cost O(1) space. And the priority queue (often implemented with heaps) costs O(k) space (it's far less than N in most situations).
```

I don't quite understand why the space is O(n) ? For me it's obviously O(k) because we only need a heap of size k. I don't see where we have created a new linked list.

Thanks.

Comment: `I don't see where we have created a new linked list.` -- You are allocating new nodes with `point.next = ListNode(val)`

Comment: In the **Approach 3**, the code definitely creates a new list. So it's O(k) for the priority queue, and O(n) for the new list.